# How can I use javascript to write <map> and <area> html tags?

Tags: javascript, html, dictionary, area

What I need to do is dynamically write area tags on to a map as they are added so that when I click on them they trigger a function.

```
    <img src="out.jpg" usemap="#mapmap"/>
    <map name="mapmap">
        <area id="1" shape="rect" coords="75,300,125,400" onclick="writeDiv(this.id)"/>
        <area id="2" shape="rect" coords="175,300,225,400" onclick="writeDiv(this.id)"/>
        <area id="3" shape="rect" coords="275,300,325,400" onclick="writeDiv(this.id)"/>
    </map>
```

That does exactly what I need if I know where areas are going to be. However, I need to load them dynamically as the user adds more and I've already tried this (in script tags):

```
    $("<img src=\"out.jpg\" usemap=\"#mapmap\"\/>").appendTo('body');
        $("<map name=\"mapmap\">").appendTo('body');
            $("<area id=\"1\" shape=\"rect\" coords=\"75,300,125,400\" onclick=\"writeDiv(this.id)\"\/>").appendTo('body');
            $("<area id=\"2\" shape=\"rect\" coords=\"175,300,225,400\" onclick=\"writeDiv(this.id)\"\/>").appendTo('body');
            $("<area id=\"3\" shape=\"rect\" coords=\"275,300,325,400\" onclick=\"writeDiv(this.id)\"\/>").appendTo('body');
        $("<\/map>").appendTo('body');
```

Which would be fine as I could still format the rest of my page around the image except that it doesn't work as you'd expect. I've already tested

```
    $("<div id=\"test\">testing text<\/div>").appendTo('body');
```

and that works to write text to the bottom of the body of my page.

So, is there a way to get this to work, or are the dependencies between  and  always going to screw it up? If you can think of another way entirely to do it I'm open to suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: Not sure i understand what you want? Do you want a button to add <area> tags to your <map>, when you click a button?

Comment: how are you generating the area tag information?

Comment: No eventually the information will be coming out of a database, containing the coordinates to where the areas need to go. I asked how to use javascript to create these area tags I'm not sure how that could be any more clear...

Comment: Try like this:
   
Better idea is to add any extra button inside loop code and then render in html, further if you want to attach event using any js then use function inside your code to call function.After loading map click and other event handler will not work

Comment: Not sure if i'm understanding your suggestion right, first of all once I connect the database it will be in a loop so theres no worry there but when programming always take it 1 step at a time; I don't need 20 fails in a loop when I can have just 1. Secondly if I use javascript to write out a just a basic button or other single line of html and add an onclick pointed to a function, it will still run the function.

Comment: May be , but after loading map ,binding of event somehow failed.

Comment: Ok thanks for nothing community, finally solved this myself by using .addElement() and then .setAttribute() and that bound the onclick event. Still very confused why appending the tags to the body didn't have any effect though.

Comment: When I faced a very similar situation, I created did a `area = document.createElement("area")` followed by setting the `area` properties.  Add that to the `map` element and bob's your uncle.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `$('<tag ...>')`, jQuery parses the HTML and creates DOM elements out of it. You're appending *elements*, not tags. Adding `<map ...>` like this creates a `<map>` element and appends it, which (if you dump the resulting HTML after appending it) will show in the document with `</map>` tag and everything.

The `<area>` elements have to go into the `<map>` element, rather than the body, in order for them to work (and generally, for the document to remain valid HTML).

```
var $map = $('<map name="mapmap">').appendTo('body');
$('<area id="1" shape="rect" coords="75,300,125,400" onclick="writeDiv(this.id)" />').appendTo($map);
$('<area id="2" shape="rect" coords="175,300,225,400" onclick="writeDiv(this.id)" />').appendTo($map);
$('<area id="3" shape="rect" coords="275,300,325,400" onclick="writeDiv(this.id)" />').appendTo($map);
// Note, no $('</map>') -- the $('<map...>') already took care of that
```